# Добавить чекбоксы в дополнительное поле пользователя в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Я хочу добавить несколько полей checkbox в настройки конкретного пользователя.
Параметров со полями checkbox будет много, по этому хочется, что бы каждый параметр со своими checkbox хранился в массиве.

Ниже - добавил один параметр с четырьмя checkbox.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );

function add_extra_info( $user )
{
?>

<tr>
    <th>
        Specialization
    </th>
    <?php
    $Specialization = esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('Specialization',$user->ID,true )); 
    $Specialization = array(
  array( 'id' => 'AAA', 'name' => 'Just a comment' )
);
    ?>
    <td>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization[0] == '1') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec1"> Оффшоры и корпоративное право зарубежных государств </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '2') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec2"> Фидуциарный сервис и трастовое право </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '3') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec3"> Аудит иностранных компаний </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '4') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec4"> Бухгалтерское сопровождение бизнеса за рубежом </label>
        <br>
        <label>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Use update_user_meta

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_info' );

function save_extra_info( $user_id )
{
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Specialization', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['Specialization[]'] ) );
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел решение! Мультичекбоксы в дополнительном поле пользователя в админе:

Добавляем функцию проверки чекбокса

```
function ac_checbox($user, $ac_value, $checkbox_name) {
$Specialization = get_user_meta($checkbox_name ,$user ); 
        $arr = explode(",", $Specialization);
for($a = 0; $a<count($arr); $a++) {

if($arr[$a] == $ac_value) return ' checked="checked" ';

} 
}
```

Добавляем сами чекбоксы

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="Person_Category">Person Category</label></th>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li><label><input value="cat1" name="Person_Category[]" <?php echo ac_checbox($user->ID, 'cat1', 'Person_Category'); ?>  type="checkbox" /> Все</label></li>
            <li><label><input value="cat2"  name="Person_Category[]" <?php echo ac_checbox($user->ID, 'cat2', 'Person_Category'); ?>  type="checkbox" /> Иностранные докладчики</label></li>
            <li><label><input value="cat3"  name="Person_Category[]" <?php echo ac_checbox($user->ID, 'cat3', 'Person_Category'); ?> type="checkbox" /> Российские докладчики</label></li>
            <li><label><input value="cat4"  name="Person_Category[]" <?php echo ac_checbox($user->ID, 'cat4', 'Person_Category'); ?> type="checkbox" /> Сотрудники GSL</label></li>
        </ul>           
    </td>
</tr>
```

Сохраняем

```
$persCat = $_POST["Person_Category"];
for($a = 0; $a<count($persCat); $a++) {
//записываем все нажатые чекбоксы в строку через ## Например: 1##2## 
$persCat_this .= $persCat[$a].',';
}
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Person_Category', sanitize_text_field($persCat_this ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Данные в $_POST хранятся не в Specialization[] а в Specialization в виде массива

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Specialization', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['Specialization'] ) );
```